# Agregar un div dentro de otro mediante JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo una div dentro de HTML un elemento DIV

```
<div class="row">

</div>
```

Y en un archivo JS tengo una funcion de JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(per){
            for (var i = 0; i < per.results.length; i++) {
                var a = $("<div class='col-md-4'>sss</div>");
                $("div .row").after(a);
                console.log(per.results[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
```

necesito que por cada elemento del JSON me cree un div y se incluya dentro del div de HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas prueba con un append.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(per){
            var a = "<div class='col-md-4'>sss</div>";
            for (var i = 0; i < per.results.length; i++) {
                $("div .row").append(a);
                console.log(per.results[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Para que tu respuesta funcione la declaración de `a` debe ir adentro del ciclo, si no lo único que pasará es que el elemento `a` irá saltando de fila en fila hasta llegar a la última

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear tu elemento `div` como ya lo vienes haciendo, después anexa el valor de tu JSON y finalmente anéxalo a tu fila

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(per){
        for (var i = 0; i < per.results.length; i++) {
            var a = $("<div class='col-md-4'></div>");
            a.append(per.results[i].name);
            $("div .row").append(a);
        }
    }
});
```